# How to resolve the cache_clases = true/false conflict using Spork, RSpec & Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec, cucumber, spork

I had problems for ages in RSpec with my models not being reloaded between Spork runs.

I eventually fixed this by changing the following line in `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

became

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

HOWEVER... while this solved the issues for RSpec, Cucumber requires that cache_classes is set to **true**. 
https://rspec.lighthouseapp.com/projects/16211/tickets/165

Is there a canonical solution to this that works for both RSpec and Cucumber and which reloads RSpec models successfully?

**Footnote**

* Other changes that I implemented to make RSpec reload models included adding the following lines to `spec_helper.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
FactoryGirl.reload
```

None of these lines solved the problem without also setting `cache_classes=true` line.

Comment: I've never needed to turn off class cacheing to get spork to work properly. I do recall an occasion where defining a factory with `Factory.define :foo, :class => Foo` would stop the Foo class from being reloaded. Specifying a class name rather than the actual class fixed that.

Comment: There does seem to be a correlation between Factory girl and the model reload issues. How do you mean when you say "Specifying a class name rather than the actual class fixed that"?

Comment: Rather than saying :class => Foo you can say :class => 'Foo'  (or :class_name => "Foo" - don't recall off the top of my head)

Comment: I'll have a play with that - I've actually found this problem even independently of the factory_girl gem being present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem, and for me it was due to Rails' threadsafe mode. Ensuring config.threadsafe! is not called in my test environment fixed it for me. This is because threadsafe mode prevents code from reloading on each request and disables automatic dependency loading, which I guess spork was relying on in each_run.

I was calling config.threadsafe! in application.rb, so I removed that call from there, and put it in development.rb and production.rb instead. Now I can leave config.cache_classes set to true, and rspec and cucumber work happily under spork. Note that I was using Mongoid in my persistence layer and Machinist instead of FactoryGirl so YMMV.

See also http://rickyrobinson.id.au/2012/07/20/when-spork-puts-a-fork-in-your-cucumber-and-a-spanner-in-your-specs

Comment: Thanks for that. I can't comment on it for the moment as I gave up on testing for quite a while! Will take another look when I'm back on it though :)